# Excel: Trimming data at specific character while leaving other data without that character

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column of serial numbers with data in one of these two forms: "XXX-YYYYY" or just "YYYYYY". What I would like to do is create a new column that trims the "XXX-" from any serial number that has it so I'm let with just the "YYYYY" part.
Ex. Initial column has: 587-57536, 19574, 912-45194 will become: 57536, 19574, 45194.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MID to return a substring from a string. You identify the position to start from using FIND, which you use to find the hyphen. If the hyphen is not found, the MID function will error, so you wrap that in IFERROR and just return the whole of the value from column A otherwise. You then use NUMBERVALUE to convert the text value returned into a number:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1)),A1))
```

[image]

Comment: This could be shortened to `=--IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,99),A1)` =) +

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the RIGHT function to extract the value that are on the right of `-`.

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("-",A1),0)>0,RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-(FIND("-",A1))),A1)
```

[image]